# TCriticalSection with many readers and one writer

Tags: multithreading, delphi, thread-safety

I have a service app written in Delphi 10 Seattle Win32 which has in-memory data that is updated regularly in a thread.

As the data is a complex structure and received in chunks, the update code writes to a temporary list and when it completes the structure switches this temporary list to a "production" list which is read by many reader threads.

I sat the "switch" code as a critical section along with the respective readers to have them mutually excluded. I realized later that as a side effect the reader threads are mutually exclusive among them too.

My question is if there is an alternative critical section class that I can characterize as reader o writer so as to allow readers to execute simultaneously.

Besides this, I protected only the reader code which gathers the data it has to send and makes copies of this data to be send after leaving the critical section. I wonder whether it should be more performant to have this data gathering code mutually exclusive anyway or serialized.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer which I think is what I was looking for.

Comment: Indeed, but do make sure you do some timings, because Emba's sync objects are not known for their efficiency

Answer (score 6):

There is [TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer) in SysUtils. (If you like your fingers, consider using the `TMREWSync` alias from the same unit.)

Keep in mind, though, that it is terribly slow and that many times a simple critical section will perform better.

As you are compiling for Windows, you may also consider using [Slim Reader/Writer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks). That one is Windows-specific, but extremely fast.

Comment: Why didn't you suggest your TOmniMREW?

Comment: Because TOmniMREW is not meant to be used by inexperienced users. It has no way to promote a lock, it cannot be nested and it eats lots of CPU while waiting for a lock.